# Apache flink external api call

Tags: apache-flink, stream-processing

Is it possible to call an external api (RESTful) inside apache flink code. If it is possible then how we can do that.

I am calling an api from simple java code, it is working fine but when i use the same code in apache flink, it throws an exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://example.com/someapi
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to call an external api (RESTful) inside apache flink code. If it is possible then how we can do that.

You can use the Async I/O feature provided in Flink Streaming API. Flink’s Async I/O API allows users to use asynchronous request clients with data streams. More details and examples [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html).

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://example.com/someapi

This seems to non-flink error since the response is 500. Check the request headers/parameters that is being sent and verify if the http request is being properly created. Try some utilities like PostMan to test the API first.